# How to redefine FocusVisualStyle for a WPF user control

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to redefine `FocusVisualStyle` for a user control (to make it more obvious in webexes) and it isn't working. Can't I just slap

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}"
       TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="-3" 
                           StrokeThickness="2"
                           Stroke="Red"
                           SnapsToDevicePixels="true" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="Control">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}}"/>
</Style>
```

into my code (in `UserControl.Resources`)? That doesn't work, though.

It works when I explicitly set the focus visual style on a particular control:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="rbGroup" TabIndex="30" 
        FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}}">
    Choice A
</RadioButton>
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Also, doesn't work if I remove the TargetType from the style and change the DynamicResource into a StaticResource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all for style to be picked automatically, **`TargetType`** should be same as that of actual control type you intend to apply that on. So, **change TargetType of Style from Control to RadioButton**.

Second, as per [**Dependency Property Value Precedence order**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), properties set in ***style setters have lesser precedence order compared to properties set in template triggers***.

In default template of RadioButton, FocusVisualStyle is set in ControlTemplate triggers. Hence, *whatever value you set in Style setters will be overriden by ControlTemplate triggers*. And since local value has higher precedence compared to controlTemplate triggers that's why setting it locally works.

---

There are two possible solutions for it -

First - Either **override complete ControlTemplate of RadioButton** and place your FocusVisualStyle there.

Second - Style triggers have higher precedence order than control template triggers, **set the focusVisualStyle in style triggers** and it will be overridden. Something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="-3" 
                            StrokeThickness="2"
                            Stroke="Red"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style TargetType="RadioButton"
       xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:Boolean.TrueString}}"
                        Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                    Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  It also works to put the trigger in a style with TargetType="Control" and then create triggers for specific types with BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Control}}".  I had to use a different style key than "{x:Static SystemParameters.FocusVisualStyleKey}" (I used "RedOutlineStyle").